# Does a JavaScript-function can be seen as an execution context respectively as this?

Tags: javascript, function, this, executioncontext

In the lower example, why does the function `outer` which is assigned as method to the object-property with the identifier `meth` does not have an execution context which would be the `this` in the `inner`-function?

Since the function `outer` assigned to `meth` seems to automatically get the `this`-keyword set to the surrounding object as execution context, you could assume, that the function `inner` is getting handled the same way, or is it because a surrounding function can not be seen as an execution context, therefore JavaScript does not know for the function `inner` which execution context it is in, so it assumes the default, which is then `window`?

```
var foo = {
    meth: function outer() {
        console.log(this);
        // let that = this;
        function inner() {
            console.log(this);
        }
        inner();
    }
};
```

```
//Output
{meth: ƒ}
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}
```

Thanks in advance for demystifying

Comment: "you could assume, that the function inner is getting handled the same way" — Why could you assume that? It is a different function that is called differently.

Comment: "*Since `outer` seems to automatically get the this-keyword set to the surrounding object as execution context*" - no, it doesn't automatically get that. Also in your code you haven't even shown how you are calling it.

Comment: The `inner` function is not called from an object. `this` refers to the object a function is called on. e.g. this [gist](https://gist.github.com/C5H8NNaO4/24fa7ee87b8f099f6de3811f97c8d44c). The behaviour is defined in the specs under [Entering Function Code - 10.4.3.2](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) and [Function Calls - 11.2.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see this code:

```
function inner() {
    console.log(this);
}
inner();
```

It really is irrelevant whether that code occurs in another function body or not, or whether that function body belongs to a method of some object, ...etc. It is irrelevant.

What is relevant is how you *call* `inner`. You call it not as `someobject.inner()`, nor with explicit binding, like `inner.call(this)`, ... so there is no binding of `this`, hence you get the default binding, which is the `window` object when running in sloppy mode, or `undefined` in strict mode.

> The function `outer` assigned to `meth` seems to automatically get the `this`-keyword set to the surrounding object as execution context

This is not assured. If you do:

```
let outer = meth.outer;
outer();
```

...then you will notice that `this` is getting the default binding as well. Again, it depends on how you *call* the function.

If you call it with the dot-notation, then you implicitly bind it with the object:

```
meth.outer();
```

So now `this` will be `meth` in the execution context of `outer`.

Comment: (except whether it occurs in a strict mode code or not)